# Google form is showing user who created the form as submitting request

Tags: google-forms

I created a google form as a work request form for my team at work. The request then goes to a google group (where all team members can access and pull from) The issue is when a request from the form comes to the google group it is showing that it was submitted by me and not by who is requesting the work, but when we go to the google spreadsheet to see the request it is showing the correct user who submitted.

How can I get the user (work email) who submitted to show in the google group?

Response to first comment-
Here is what a work request looks like coming into our group inbox (google group)

[image]

This is showing as being sent by Shaun, but I (Jessica) as in the second picture shows was the requester who filled out this work request
[image]

Comment: Obvious answer: copy the info from the spreadsheet to the group. Presumably there's more to this, though, so more details needed. How does the request "go to a google group"? How is "submitter" shown? DO YOU HAVE SOME CODE?

Comment: Summary updated with pictures

Answer (score 0):

It appears that **Shaun** is the owner of the spreadsheet receiving the input from the google form, and/or the author of the script that generates an email from the form input and sends it to the google group. You don't say so explicitly, but I would guess that you're using a "Collaborative inbox" group type.

Since the email to the group comes from Shaun, that is the user profile that is displayed on the message, above the message content.

[image: screenshot]

Possible options that fail:

- While you can specify a different "from" address when sending an email via the GMail Google Apps Script service, you are limited to using your own registered aliases - so that isn't going to help you.
- Instead of emailing the completed form, have the script generate the whole group entry on behalf of the Requestor (sic). Despite a [7-year-old feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=27), there is no API that supports this.

So what will work?

If you're willing to forego the form and spreadsheet, each requester can send their own email, which will ensure that their credentials are used to display a user profile on the groups page. To guide use of standardized fields, you can provide a `mailto` link with the body of the email pre-formatted for users.

```
mailto:work-group@googlegroups.com?subject=Work+Request&body=Request+Type:+%0dProgram:+%0dWork+Package+Name:+
```

[image: Email]

Such a `mailto` link can be embedded on a web page, or kept as a browser shortcut to make it easy on users.

Comment: The reason we went to a form was there are many different things people can request from our team. Emails already come to our inbox and we have to figure out exactly what the user wants.